# React Native navigation push duplicate same screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am making chat app on react native.

While I am on the chat screen when I click to the notification I pushing new chat screen. But previous chat screen still run. If app going to background, app write to

> 1active 2active

```
 this.props.navigation.push({
                        routeName: goScreenName,
                        params:goScreenParameters  });
```

this event causes the socket problem, how can I fix this problem without StackActions.reset?

```
 _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {

            if (nextAppState.match(/inactive|background/)) {
                socket.emit('leaveRoom', "")
                console.log(this.state.chatID+"background ")
            }
            if (nextAppState.match(/active/)) {
                console.log(this.state.chatID+"active");
                socket.emit('chatRoom', this.state.chatID);
            }
          }
```

Comment: well.. you are `push`ing a new route on the stack.. its a stacknavigator right? why dont you try `replace`? also if its the stack navigator then via [their docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html) they have `replace` and `reset` methods to help clear the stack.

Comment: yea its stacknavigator

Comment: yea so you can replace or pop views off the stack. `this.props.navigation.pop` or `this.props.navigation.replace`

Comment: you want `this.props.navigation.pop` to navigate back to the active chat. or another way you could fix it is by not pushing on the stack from chat. (so that it isn't a background item)